# Parsing network data

Tags: parsing, networking, hex, wireshark, packet

When parsing network data, is there any sort of procedure to determine what sort of frame you see in a packet?

For example, I can see some packets that are Ethernet II, or IEEE 802.3. Is there a way of figuring out which interface you are looking at just by reading the bits?

Comment: Do you have access to the entire packet capture/interface or just the packets? You can generally determine the next layer/PDU because there will be a field for it, but not the reverse.

Comment: If you are receiving, then look at the destination MAC address. For sending, look at the source MAC address. You can then see which interface in your host sent or received the frame because you have the address of the interface in question.